# How to show that $P(B \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve some probability problems. One of them is the [taxi problem](https://plus.maths.org/content/solution-taxi-problem-revisited).

In the solution of this (and other) problem(s), there's an equation: $P(B \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$, that is: the probability of the event *B* given NOT *A* is 1 minus the probability of *B* given *A*.

While I can understand the "real-life" meaning of the equation in the taxi problem, I fail to prove it using just formulas. I made many attempts, using the definition of conditional probability, Bayes formula, the law of total probability. The last attempt I made led me to the conclusion $P(B | \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$ iff $P(A) + P(B) = 1$, which can't be true in the case of the taxi problem.

Therefore, I'm asking:

1. Is it really true that $P(B \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$?
2. Is it always true or just for certain $B$ and for certain $A$?
3. If the equation can't be verified, how come the taxi problem can be solved using it?

Comment: I edited for proper use of \mid, and you see that it looks different that way.

Comment: The probability I win the lottery (if it's raining) plus the probability I win the lottery (if it's not raining) is NOT one.  Perhaps you meant $P(\overline{B}|A)=1-P(B|A)$.

Comment: If $P(B)=0$, then $P(B|C)=0$ for any event $C$ whatsoever, so the equation $$P(B\mid \overline{A})=1-P(B\mid A)$$ can't possibly be true.

Comment: It is not generally true that $P(B\mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B\mid A)$.  It is true that $P(\overline{B}\mid A)=1-P(B\mid A)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Then how can the solution proposed on the web page I linked (and on many other web pages) work?

Comment: @heyhey: The website **you** linked to says, **verbatim**:

`(It happens in this case that P(B|not A) = 1 - P(B|A); please note, however, that this result is not generally true.)`

Comment: @ZevChonoles: ah, sorry. It's late here, I must have missed that note. But anyhow, why is the equation true in this case? How to justify it using only theorems and axioms?

Comment: The solution doesn't rely on that equation holding; it just happens to hold in this particular case.

Comment: @BrianTung: yes, it does. Otherwise, how do you calculate $P(B)$?

Comment: @heyhey You calculate $P(B)$ by knowing $P(B\mid A)$, $P(B \mid \bar A)$, and $P(A)$. The formula that computes $P(B)$ from those values does not rely on having $P(B\mid A) = 1 - P(B \mid \bar A)$; if it made that assumption then it would only need to use one of those values as input.

Comment: Mh, now I see. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $P(B \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$ is not always true, as others have commented. The fact that it is true in the taxi problem is related to the independence of the events 'the taxi is blue' and 'the witness is correct'.

Remember that two events $X$ and $Y$ are called independent if $P(X$ and $Y) = P(X)P(Y)$.

I claim that the following is true: $P(B \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(B \mid A)$ if and only if $(A)$ and $(B \text{ XOR }A)$ are independent. XOR is shorthand for 'exclusive or', which is the disjoint union of $(A \text{ and } B)$ and $(\overline{A} \text{ and } \overline{B})$.

A general proof of this is a simple exercise in algebra and set theory, which I will spell out here if you want.

In the taxi example, $A$ is 'the taxi is blue' and $B$ is 'the witness says the taxi is blue'. Then $B \text{ XOR }A$ is '(the taxi is blue and the witness says blue) or (the taxi is red and the witness says red)'. In other words, $B \text{ XOR } A$ is simply 'the witness is correct', which is independent from $A$.